# Reading table in R language

Tags: r, list

I'm starting to program in R language and I'm trying to read data from a .txt file. I have the data written in lines (one value on each one), and I try to assign it to a vector x in the following way, in order to obtain a vector containing all the values to work with it:

x<-c(read.table("/R/data.txt", header=FALSE))

The problem is that although the values are recognised and correctly read, I get the data in format "list" instead of "data.frame", so when trying to operate with the vector (for example, trying to do 3*x), I get an error saying it is a non-numeric argument. If useful, when asking for the value of x, i get

$V1

and then all the values which were on the file, but as "list". My intention is to be able to read those values as a data frame, instead of list, in order to do an statistical study (mean(x), median(x), etc).

Thank you very much.

Comment: try `unlist(x)` and see what happens.  Also `str(x)` will describe the properties of the `x` object.

Comment: When unlisting, I get the separate values with a "header" consisting of V1 and the position in the list (V11, V12, ..., V179 for 79 elements). Also str(x) gives: "List of 1
 $ V1: int [1:79] 5 13 4 6 9 3 13 4 1 13 ..."

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
clarify title of question, improve code formatting,
 provide more information about the problem: 
results
,
 and anything else that can help us solve your problem.
See [ask]

Comment: Also str(x) gives: "List of 1 $ V1.  That looks like a data frame with a single column.  If you set x2 <- unlist(x), that will give you a vector of numbers with names.  If you set x2 <- x[[1]] that will extract the data frame from the list.

Comment: hi,
can you post the first three lines of the text file?

Comment: Thank you, this way it worked out well. Despite when doing class(x2) i get "integer", instead of "data.frame", but it is useful anyway to work with the values.

Comment: @Cettt , I didn't know how to create a .txt file so I found that in my laptop notebook I could save files as .txt. The text file was 79 numbers from 1 to 13 written in 79 lines, separated by "returns" (what you get when pressing enter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read.table` returns a data.frame by default. A data.frame is a special type of list.
If you want a vector instead try this:

```
x <- read.table("myfile.txt", header = FALSE)[,1]
```

Comment: Thank you, I've finally solved the problem. After x<-read.table(...) I've done x<-x[[1]], and the resultant is already a vector.